# Can't add Loopcuts to Filled in planes?

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to add a loopcut to a filled in part of my mesh.
why won't it work?[image]

Comment: loop cuts only work with quads. You have an N-gon, composed of multiple edges, but in this case, it is easy to keep quad geometry so you can do loop cuts.